# How can I write this simple algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, logic

this is my very first stackoverflow question.
 
I'm not a native speaker, but I study mainly in english, and I've tried to search this around the internet with different approaches to my text but I couldn't find anything.

And i'm having trouble to find some directions to write a simple code that follows something like this:

*example*:

> We have a set of values, for example, characters from a game, or flags from a country, etc.

Suposing we have three flags: Japan, Usa and Israel.

- We inform to the user these values, so then he knows what are the possible picks, and choose one.
- Then, the algorithm make questions like: "Is the blue color present in this flag? yes or no?"
   
  (if the answer is yes, than the algorithm eliminates Japan, for example)
- Then the algorithm make some more pertinent questions until just one flag is left.
  "You chose the flag of United States."

I know stackoverflow maybe it's not intended for such simple and beginner questions, but if I could have any clue on how to develop this simple algorithm maybe it would help me on how to apply if statements and things like that into my codes and my current ideas. I'm learning ***Python*** and Math by myself currently, and every small step is very enlightening.

> If someone could fill me in with some Python structure for this or, or pseudocode, or even what phrase should I google,  it would mean a lot to me.

*Sorry for my bad english!*

Comment: Questions asking us to write code for your requirements are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they are not about solving a specific problem with code, but rather are asking the community to do your work for you. Instead, make an attempt at writing code and if you encounter a problem, narrow the question to that specific problem and show what has been done so far to try solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to prepare a list of questions first, then with each question, you will have a list of remaining answers. After asking a bunch of questions, you will get the final answer as you wish.

For example, I will have a dictionary storing questions for the flag examples above:
`list_options = [{'q': 'does the blue present in the flag?', 'y':['israel'], 'n': ['japan', 'usa']}, {'q': 'is the circle in the flag?', 'y': ['japan'], 'n': ['usa']}]`

So at each step, you throw a question to the user and eliminate some answers until you get the last one.
Hope this could help

Comment: Really helped. Thanks.